# Взаимодействие классов ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream, Runnable с JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, io

В общем, в потоке JavaFX у меня запускаются два других потока Server и Client. Соответственно нужно как-то в клиент из потока JavaFX передать параметр writeObject, но когда я пытаюсь это сделать вылетает NullPointerException.. При использовании Service и Task вообще ничего не происходило... Как передать информацию из этого *** JavaFX в другой поток или в чём тут ещё может быть проблема?

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Client c = new Client();

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        try {
            menu = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("smth.fxml"));
            loading = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("paw.fxml"));
            game = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("game.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        scene1 = new Scene(menu);
        scene = new Scene(loading);
        scene2 = new Scene(game);
        Main.stage = stage;
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1500), actionEvent -> {
            stage.setScene(scene1);
        })).play();
    }
    @FXML
    private Button b1;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        b1.setOnAction(ae -> {
            new Thread(c).start();
            c.sendData("Hello");
        });
    }
}

public class Client implements Runnable {

    private static Socket connection;
    private static ObjectInpurStream input;
    private static ObjectOutputStream output;

    public void run() {
        try {
            connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(IP), 3112);
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendData(Object object){
        try {
            output.writeObject(object);
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

В общем есть ещё сервер, но не думаю, что его надо описывать.. Клиент к нему подключается, там всё нормально работает. Но, когда я пытаюсь отправить эту несчастную строчку, вылетает NullPointerException... В общем-то я новичок в Java, поэтому тяжело сообразить куда копать надо

Comment: Пожалуйста, приложите минимально воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Этот *** JavaFX вообще ни при чем. Вопрос во взаимодействии потоков (это ключевые слова при гуглении, кстати), а не в JavaFX. Попробуйте сделать сначала просто в консоли, а потом уже прикрутить JavaFX.

Comment: подскажите, если можно это как-то исправить, я просто вообще тупенький

Answer (score 0):

У вас инициализация поле `output` происходит в новом потоке, а send в основном потоке, так во время `output.writeObject(),` output ещё не успел инициализироваться .